# Remove part of name of multiple files on mac os

Tags: bash, macos, file-rename

i have a directory full of .png files with a random caracters in the middle of the filenames like

```
T1_021_É}ÉcÉjÉV_solid box.png
T1_091_ÉRÉjÉtÉ@Å[_City.png
T1_086_ÉnÉiÉ~ÉYÉL_holiday.png
```

I expect this after removing

```
T1_021_solid box.png
T1_091_City.png
T1_086_holiday.png
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `for` to collect the file lists and bash *parameter expansion with substring removal*, you can do the following in the directory containing the files:

```sh
for i in T1_*; do 
    beg="${i%_*_*}"             ## trim from back to 2nd '_'
    end="${i##*_}"              ## trim from from through last '_'
    mv "$i" "${beg}_$end"       ## mv file to new name.
done
```

(**note:** you don't have to use variables `beg` and `end` you can just combing both parameter expansions to form the new filenaame, e.g. `mv "$i" "${i%_*_*}_${i##*_}"`, up to you, but `beg` and `end` make things a bit more readable.)

**Result**

New file names:

```
$ ls -al T1_*
T1_021_solid
T1_086_holiday.png
T1_091_City.png
```

Just another way to approach it from bash only.

**Using `cut`**

You can use `cut` to remove the 3rd field using `'_'` as the delimiter with :

```sh
for i in T1_*; do
    mv "$i" $(cut -d'_' -f-2,4- <<< "$i")
done
```

(same output)

The only drawback is the use of `cut` in the command substitution would require an additional subshell be spawned each iteration.

Comment: works like a charme. thanks for nice explanation

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 0):

If the set of random  characters have _ before and after

```
find . -type f -iname "T1_0*" 2>/dev/null | while read file; do 
    mv "${file}" "$(echo ${file} | cut -d'_' -f1,2,4-)"
done
```

**Explanation**:

- Find all files that start with T1_
- Read the list line by line using the while loop
- Use _ as delimiter and cut the 3rd column
- Use mv to rename

Filenames after renaming:

```
T1_021_solid box.png
T1_086_holiday.png
T1_091_City.png
```